# Change function from bold to underline

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that makes some text passages bold. It randomly selects words from a div and makes them bold. I'd like to have the same exact function, but instead of making the text bold, it should make the words underline.

The end result should be that some words are bold and some words are underlined.

Here is my function that makes random words bold.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    function bold() {
        var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
        var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                wordCount = words.length;
                var newHTML = "";
                var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<b>";
                    newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                    if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</b>";
                    target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                }
                oldHTML = newHTML;
            }
        };
    };
    $('#randomText').load("hier.txt", bold)
})

});
```

My idea was to just copy the function, and change a few things:

```
$(function() {
    function underline() {
        var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
        var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                wordCount = words.length;
                var newHTML = "";
                var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<u>";
                    newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                    if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</u>";
                    target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                }
                oldHTML = newHTML;
            }
        };
    };
    $('#randomText').load("hier.txt", underline)
})
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the result you get? And why write an entire new function? Can't you just add the underline part in the existing function?

Comment: You're overwriting the contents of `#randomText`. When you run `$('#randomText').load("hier.txt", underline)` you lose all the changes made by your `bold` function.

Comment: The result is that, when the bold function is below the underline function, the words will randomly be bold but not underline. Whenever the underline function is below the bold function, the words will be randomly underline but not bold.

Comment: `load("hier.txt")` wil load a new text file

Comment: I only wrote '$('#randomText').load("hier.txt", bold, underline)' and it still does not work.

Comment: try `$('#randomText').load('hier.txt', function () { bold(); underline(); });`.

Comment: You're the best. Thanks man this is working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to get bold or underlined text, which is the `execCommand` function.
**For example:**

```
<body>
    <button onclick='bold()'>Bold</button>
    <button onclick='underline()'>Underline</button>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Bold(){
    richTextField.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
}

function Underline(){
   richTextField.document.execCommand('underline',false,null);
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Comment: Thanks for your solution but we're trying to randomize the words and make them automatically bold and underlined.

Comment: I know, but you can use  a build-in function (`execCommand`) instead of making your own. You can randomize the words with a `for` loop as you did, and with `Math.random`. When `Math.random` gives for example a 1-10  number you can use a bold or underline function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge,chrome = 1">
      <title>Hello World </title>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="randomText">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

    function bold() {
        var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
        var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                wordCount = words.length;
                var newHTML = "";
                var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<b>";
                    newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                    if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</b>";
                    target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                }
                oldHTML = newHTML;
            }
        };
    };


function underline() {
        var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
        var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                wordCount = words.length;
                var newHTML = "";
                var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<u>";
                    newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                    if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</u>";
                    target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                }
                oldHTML = newHTML;
            }
        };
    };
    $('#randomText').load("hier.txt", bold);
    $('#randomText').load("hier.txt", underline);
});
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```